# Почему не работает keyboard в telegram bot api?

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Я ввожу в telegram сообщение "message", но в результате он не присылает мне ничего. Помогите, пожалуйста исправить

https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token;

```
$updates = file_get_contents("php://input");
$result = (array)json_decode($updates, true);

$text = $result["message"]["text"];
$chatId = $result["message"]["from"]["id"];

if($text == "message") {
    $url = $website;
    $url .= "/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($text);
    $current_board = array(array("1", "2"), array("3", "4"));
    sendMessageKeyboard($url, $current_board);

} else if($text == "платёж") {
    $provider_token = "381764678:TEST:5058"; 
    $product_name = "Свежие мандарины"; //title
    $product_description = "Доставляем недорогие мандарины по приемлемой цене"; //description
    $payload = "67192"; //payload  это shopId
    $start_parameter = "352780"; //это shopArticleId
    $currency = "RUB"; //currency
    $prices = json_encode(array("label" => "мандарин", "amount" => 45));

    $url = $website;
    $url .= "/sendInvoice?chatId=".$chatId."&title=".$product_name."&description=".$product_description;
    $url .= "&payload=".$payload."&provider_token=".$provider_token.="&start_parameter=".$start_parameter;
    $url .= "&currency=".$currency."&prices=".$prices;

    file_get_contents($url);
} else if($text == "/startgame") {
    $url = $website;
    $url .= "/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($message);
    $current_board = array(array("Физика", "Химия"), array("Физика", "Химия"));
    sendMessageKeyboard($url, $current_board);
} else { 
    sendMessage($website, $chatId, $text);
}

/*$fp = fopen('file.txt', 'a');
$writing = fwrite($fp, $error);
if($writing) {
    echo 'Данные успешно занесены';
} else {
    echo "Ошибка загрузки файла";
}

fclose($fp);
*/


function sendMessage($site, $chat_id, $message) {
    $url = $site;
    $url .= "/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($message);

    file_get_contents($url);
}

function sendMessageKeyboard($curl, $keyboard) {
    $reply = json_encode(array("keyboard" => $keyboard, "resize_keyboard" => true, "one_time_keyboard" => true));
    $add_url = $curl;
    $add_url .= "&reply_markup=";
    $add_url .= $reply;
    file_get_contents($add_url);
}
```

?>`введите сюда код`

Answer (score 0):

с виду всё верно, но нет возможности проверить.
если ответа от бота нет - произошла ошибка на стороне php, в этом случае поможет функция для отладки:

```
function debug($arg){
        if($arg==""){$arg="empty variable...";}
        die(self::sendMessage(*id вашего чата*, print_r(json_decode(json_encode($arg),true),true)));
    }
```

перепишите её под свой стиль. функция работает по образу var_dump(), но в чат бота, таким образом можно находить места где работа скрипта ломается (если сообщения от функции приходят, а после переноса на 10 строк ниже уже не приходят - проблема в этом промежутке).

так же советую переписать немного логику, ваша `sendMessage` принимает `$url` который никогда не меняется, а так же есть переменные, которые много где используются и везде их надо передавать (по хорошему под это надо сделать отдельный класс).

так же может быть и такая ситуация: вебхуки иногда просто отваливаются (из за черезмерного количества ошибок php) и его надо ставить заново. вам об этом никак не сообщат.

Comment: у меня возник ещё один вопрос. Не знаешь ли, что за параменты такие payload и start_parameter в методе sendInvoice в Telegram Bot API?